# Tableau bar chart - how to color each bar different

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api

I have a vertical bar chart plotting sales figures by age ranges (15-20, 20-25 etc).

Currently, all ten bars I have are blue in color.

For purely aesthetic purposes, I would like to make each bar either a different color entirely (probably too outlandish though), or a different shade of blue. Can either/both of these be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both can be done. You can achieve this if you drag the 'measure values' onto the color shelf. You can then edit the colors so all the other measures are one color or you also select single color with different shades.

Hope this is what you are after, but if not please post back.